# Confused about how is_valid works

Tags: python, django

I have a view which validates data from a form which just has some basic information about an item. I'm confused with how the `is_valid` method works here even after reading 
[this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-subclasses-and-modifying-field-errors) . If the user doesn't input some of the required fields like name or image 1, I want them to see the error on the page "this field is required" or something of that nature. I thought if the `form.is_valid` returned `False`, these messages would automatically be raised on the page for the user. Or do I need to specify what error message for each field somewhere that I would want the user see?

```
    #view
            def sell(request):
                if request.method == "POST":
                    form = AddItem(request.POST, request.FILES)
                    if form.is_valid():
                        item = form.save(commit=False)
                        item.user = request.user
                        item.is_active = True
                        item.slug = slugify(item.name)
                        item.save()
                        return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks.html')  
                else:
                    form = AddItem()
                    return render_to_response('forsale.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    #form    
        class AddItem(forms.ModelForm):
            name = forms.CharField(label="Title")


            class Meta:
                model = Item
                exclude = ('user','slug','is_active',)

#model

class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
    image1 =  models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
    image2 =  models.ImageField(upload_to='img', blank=True)
    image3 =  models.ImageField(upload_to='img', blank=True)
    image_caption1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    image_caption2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    image_caption3 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    description = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    shipping_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extract the errors from the form object using `form.errors` then deal with the dict however you want.  If you're using ajax, simply send the dict as json back over and use javascript to handle it.  If it was a direct html form submit, then you need to render and respond with a page with the errors in the passed dictionary and deal with the passed error in the template (usually with an `{% if errors %}` tag